# Firebase Changing layout of child data information in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase data structure:

[image: Firebase]

And when printing out this in my app, it goes like:

[image: App result]

How do I change this? so it doesn't display it with commas? but instead new lines

In Android, I just had a code that retrieves all the values from child "ingredients"

Comment: Use for each child in your on datachabged

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: please add some code and explain more what you want to do

Comment: query = reference.child("recipes").child(label).child("ingredients");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot recipe : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        results.add(recipe.getKey());
                        results.add(recipe.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This is the code: and it prints out the ingredients with commas in between each one of them, how do I separate them by new lines?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've stored your ingredients in an array. Firebase treats arrays as one object; elements cannot be added, changed or removed. The only option with arrays is to re-write the entire array to maintain a sequential index.

The bottom line is that arrays should generally be avoided in Firebase. See this Firebase blog about them [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Also, if you want a lot more information, search here for 'Arrays Are Evil'

There are a number of other ways to store your data which are much more flexible. For example

```
-Yuyijiomapsd
   dish_name: "Jay's Spaghetti Sauce"
   ingredients
     -Yhiipkpokosd
        name: "Garlic"
     -Yu8jj99s9jis
        name: "Basil"
     -Yijijjis99ss
        name: "Red Wine"
```

Each key like -Yhiipkpokosd, is generated with childByAutoId or push().

This structure is amazingly flexible as it can be expanded...

```
-Yuyijiomapsd
   dish_name: "Jay's Spaghetti Sauce"
   ingredients
     -Yhiipkpokosd
        name: "Garlic"
        qty: "Two cloves, minced"
     -Yu8jj99s9jis
        name: "Basil"
        qty: "1/2 cup"
     -Yijijjis99ss
        name: "Red Wine"
        qty: "As much as you like"
```

You can also query it with a Deep Query, so for example, you could query the entire database for all recipes that have Red Wine in them.

Comment: How do I create a structure like this? I added data to the database using json. This is how I added ingredients: "ingredients": [ "Garlic", "Basil", "Tagliatelle", "Olive Oil", "Tin of quality plum tomatoes", "Asparagus"],

Comment: See [Basic Write Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for an example of doing it in code. That example writes a userName and email to a node but you can extrapolate from there.

Comment: So I can only do this from Android? not from just create a Json file and adding to Firebase?

Comment: @lalap Of course. Web, REST, iOS, Android. The guides on the Firebase website cover all of the platforms. You can also manually use the Firebase console to add data as well in any structure. You can also import JSON too. Lots of options!

Comment: Oh okay I'll look into that, it's just because I don't know how to structure it in JSON

Comment: Hi, I changed it to a List but still prints out the same way with commas, then changed it to HashMap and still prints out same

Comment: The answer I provided was an answer to *this* question - changing the layout to better serve your apps needs. It looks like you have a different question. Perhaps posting your code and the structure I suggested in a different question would be in order?