# How to properly set Firebase Realtime Database to avoid null value at the beginning of array?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm new to NoSQL database. Currently I'm trying to use the Firebase and integrate it with iOS. When it comes to predefine the database, with trial and error, I try to make it look like this:

[image]

When I tried to retrieve the "stories" path in iOS, I get json structure like this:

```
[
    <null>,
    {
        comments: [
            <null>,
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        desc: "Blue versus red in a classic battle of good versus evil and right versus wrong.",
        duration: 30,
        rating: 4.42,
        tags: [
            <null>,
            "fantasy",
            "scifi"
        title: "The Order of the Midnight Sun",
        writer: 1
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is, why there's always a null at the beginning of each array? What should I do in the database editor to avoid the null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you start pushing data to index 1 and not 0, inserting/retrieving data to/from a list starts with index 0:

[image]

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't think that the number means anything at all. I just "forced" to put anything to the key, so I just put (random) numbers, which in this case a series of number starts from 1. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenLiYong In general, Array's should be avoided in NoSQL Databases. They are not queryable, or editable and if you wan to change something you have read and then re-write the entire array. There are much better alternatives. Please take a look at this Firebase Article [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862) with some addtionial info.