# Appending an array within a post rather than creating a new post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a comment section for my open source social media app. I have a table of posts. When you click a post in this table, it takes you to the MainViewController, where you can read the comments on those posts and post your own comment. The Post class is as follows:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
var id:String
var title: String
var text:String
var createdAt:Date
var comment: [String] = []

init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double, comment: [String] = []) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)




}
static func parse(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Post? {
    if let title = data["text"] as? String,
        let text = data["title"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {
        return Post(id: key, title: title,  text: text, timestamp:timestamp, comment: [])
        }


    return nil
    }
}
```

And the MainTextViewController has the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainTextView: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var commentsTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var commentPlaceHolder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newCommentLabel: UITextView!
weak var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?

@IBAction func reply(_ sender: UIButton) {

// Firebase code here
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let postObject = [
        "comment": newCommentLabel.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]
        ] as [String : Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }  else {
            // Handle error

        }
    })
    newCommentLabel.text = String()
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = false
}
var post: Post?

// MARK: - View Controller LifeCycle

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setMain()

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(delegate!)
    commentsTable.dataSource = post?.comment as? UITableViewDataSource
    newCommentLabel.delegate = self


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return post!.comment.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:50))
    cell.addSubview(label)
    return cell
}


// UITableViewDelegate Functions

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

private func setMain() {
    guard let post = self.post else {
        return
    }

    titleText.text = post.text
    mainText.text = post.title
}
func textViewDidChange(_ commentView: UITextView) {

    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = !newCommentLabel.text.isEmpty

    }
}
```

Here is my database structure:

```
  {
  "posts" : {
    "-LhaxLOSY3UI7tDUrCA_" : {
      "text" : "Nelson",
      "timestamp" : 1560800488059,
      "title" : "Hey\t"
    },
    "-LhaxbnjgDP7tdb7Eq_4" : {
      "text" : "Lol",
      "timestamp" : 1560800558514,
      "title" : "How’s it going"
    },
    "comment" : {
      "comment" : "Howdy"
    }
  }
}
```

I want that when I make a comment, it appends the comments array for the post with a new comment. Then everyone can see the comments in the commentsTable as a collection of strings from the array with the oldest one on top.

At the moment, creating a new comment makes a new post in Firebase with just a comment as a single string and a timestamp. How would you fix this issue so that the post button appends the table and the commentsTable shows the strings from the array? Let me know if you need me to post more details. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please don't use arrays with NoSQL databases. They are very difficult to work with and as you've discovered cannot really be used like a typical array in code would be used. Generally Arrays are Evil so see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179477/firebase-changing-layout-of-child-data-information-in-android/43191862#43191862). The question really contains too much code and it's a tad unclear what you're trying to do. It sounds like when a user adds a post, you want to append it to the existing posts? If so, can you include a snippet of your Firebase structure?

Comment: I will check that out. Here are screenshots of my database: https://imgur.com/a/Ml4KwS3

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please include it in your *question* as links break which would invalidate the question. You may also want to clarify what the *comment* node is used for - is that supposed to be a comment to post? Can there be more than one comment per post? What other data goes with the *comment*?

Comment: There can be more than one comment per post. They will be posted chronologically like 4Chan. I would like to timestamp comments and track the number of times a comment is reported. I made this report function for posts that I want to apply to comments: "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? { let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Report") { action, index in self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }"  I want to track how many reports each post and comment is getting for moderation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going overboard with a bunch of code, conceptually, if you want to have a series of posts, and then each post can additionally have comments, here's one option for a structure.

```
posts
   post_id_0
      text: "some text"
      timestamp: "20190601"
      title: "post title"
      post_uid: "uid_0"

comments
   comment_id_0
      belongs_to_post: "post_id_0"
      comment: "a comment about the post"
      timestamp: "20190601"
      comment_uid: "uid_49"
   comment_id_1
      belongs_to_post: "post_id_0"
      comment: "check out that first post!"
      timestamp: "20190602"
      comment_uid: "uid_102"

users
   uid_0
      name: "Leroy"
```

then attach observers to posts and comments. When a new post is posted, you'll be notified of that post and can add it to your tableView datasource and refresh the tableView.

When a new comment is added, you'll be notified of that comment and add it to the comments dataSource and reload the comments tableView. To add a new post:

```
let thisPostRef = your_firebase.posts.childByAutoId()
thisPostRef.setValue(your_post_data)
```

and to add a comment

```
let postKey = the_post.key
let commentRef = your_firebase.comments.childByAutoId()
commentRef.setValue(your_comment_data)
```

and your_comment_data would include a child node 'belongs_to_post: postKey'

You can also watch for comments on certain posts, made by certain users or even query for comments by date or in a date range.

Code wise, both posts and comments nodes are created with .childByAutoId - it's best practice to disassociate node keys from the data they contain, unless it going to be static data, like a uid.

If you want to add a bit more flexibility, you could keep a child node within each posts of it's related comments as well.

```
posts
   post_id_0
      text: "some text"
      timestamp: "20190601"
      title: "post title"
      post_uid: "uid_0"
      comments:
         comment_id_0: true
         comment_id_1: true
```

but that depends on what kinds of queries you want to run.

Note: I separate the comments structure from the posts the posts node as denormalizing  your data is very beneficial when running queries.

Comment: To learn to implement these types of structures and apply them to my code and present them in my tableViews, would you recommend the Firebase documentation or is there a more direct resource?

Comment: @RyanSchiller The Firebase documentation is very very good, and will get you started. There are a couple of excellent resources [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) is older but very on point. If you are an SQL'er [Firebase For SQL](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). And also the Firebase team has a some videos available on youtube as well. Lastly, is this site. SO has a wealth of Q&A's that cover just about everything dealing with Firebase.